# Error en print en sumlimetext

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Realizando esto tan sencillo:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print("Hola", end = "")
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> File "condicional1 in1.py", line 3
>
> print("Hola", end = "")
>                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ***Repl Closed***

Alguien me podría decir que está fallando?

Comment: Hola, tenemos que entender que es 'python'? en ese caso, google: 'python for'

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene por que esa sintaxis es de **python 3.x** y estas ejecutando en **python 2.7** seguramente. En python 3.x *print* es una funcion y tiene parametros opcionales como el *end* que estas utilizando.

El resultado ejecutando esas 2 lineas de codigo con **python 3.6** es:

```
HolaHolaHola
```

---

Este codigo adaptado a **python 2.7** seria:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print "Hola",
```

---

Pero el resultado seria:

```
Hola Hola Hola
```

---

Para que no deje el espacio hay que utilizar la funcion sys.stdout.write de esta manera

```
import sys

for i in [1,2,3]:
    sys.stdout.write("Hola")
```

Comment: Gracias me funciona con tu sugerencia, pero tengo instalado el Phyton 3.8, me parece muy raro.